# How do I get the id of my newly created document in android studio?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Been trying to get the id from my new product hashmap to send to another activity but from the logD ive been only getting the collection name eg. Products and not eg.Jfchd1jff3k<- randomly generated id from Firestore is there a way i can get it right after creation?

```
enter code here
```

public class newProduct extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private Button  addProduct;
private EditText productName, productDescription, productPrice;
private Spinner category;
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
FirebaseFirestore fStore;
FirebaseUser fUser;
StorageReference storageReference;
private String userID;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_product);

    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    fUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
    fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

    addProduct = findViewById(R.id.btn_addProduct);
    productName = findViewById(R.id.et_productName);
    productDescription = findViewById(R.id.et_productDescription);
    productPrice = findViewById(R.id.et_productPrice);
    category = findViewById(R.id.catSpinner);



    String[] arraySpinner = new String[]{
            "Yoga", "Lifting", "Water Sports", "Pilates", "Other"
    };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arraySpinner);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    category.setAdapter(adapter);


    addProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            saveProduct();

        }
    });

}


private void saveProduct(){
    userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DocumentReference df = fStore.collection("Users").document(userID);
    DocumentReference df2 = fStore.collection("Instructors").document(userID);
    String name = productName.getText().toString();
    String description = productDescription.getText().toString();
    String price = productPrice.getText().toString();
    String cat = category.getSelectedItem().toString();


    if(name.trim().isEmpty() || description.trim().isEmpty() || price.trim().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Fields Cannot Be Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    df.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if(documentSnapshot.getString("isuser") != null){

                String userContact = documentSnapshot.getString("Mobile");

                CollectionReference productsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("Products");
                Map<String, Object> product = new HashMap<>();
                product.put("userID", userID);
                product.put("productName", name);
                product.put("productDescription", description);
                product.put("price", price);
                product.put("category", cat);
                product.put("contact", userContact);
                productsRef.add(product);

                //this is the part where i try to get the id
                String id= productsRef.getId();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), saveProductImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("productID", id);
                startActivity(intent);

                finish();

            }else{
                df2.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                        if(documentSnapshot.getString("isinstructor") !=null){
                            String userContact = documentSnapshot.getString("Mobile");

                            CollectionReference productsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                                    .collection("Products");
                            Map<String, Object> product = new HashMap<>();
                            product.put("userID", userID);
                            product.put("productName", name);
                            product.put("productDescription", description);
                            product.put("price", price);
                            product.put("category", cat);
                            product.put("contact", userContact);
                            productsRef.add(product);

                            finish();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: So what is wrong with this code? Have you tried to get the value of the id in the next activity?

Comment: yes ive used intent.getStringExtra("ProductID") in the other activity to get the value but from my logD, instead of the id im getting "Products" which is the collection name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the ID of the document that you create, please change the following line of code:

```
String id= productsRef.getId();
```

To:

```
String id= productsRef.document().getId();
```

Add it to your `intent` object :

```
intent.putExtra("productID", id);
```

And read it back in the second activity like this:

```
String id = intent.getStringExtra("ProductID");
Lod.d("TAG", id);
```

And it should print in the console the ID of the last document that is added in Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Yes because your are trying to get it from collection which does not have ID. Document itself has id which can be created by simply calling ref.document() and returns document with it's id.

Try this

```
CollectionReference productsRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Products");
    Map<String, Object> product = new HashMap<>();
    product.put("userID", userID);
    product.put("productName", name);
    product.put("productDescription", description);
    product.put("price", price);
    product.put("category", cat);
    product.put("contact", userContact);
    DocumentReference productDocumentRef = productsRef.document();
    productDocumentRef.set(product);
```

And then get id by

```
String id= productDocumentRef.getId();
```